# duplicate symbol '_FT_New_Memory' while compile freetype2

Tags: c, makefile, freetype

I'm trying to compile freetype2 by myself.
To be simple, I just compile some basic files under base folder first.
However, I meet duplicate symbol issue while link the object.
I'm unfamiliar with makefile and FreeType.
Could someone help me solve this?

```
CC:=g++
SRCS = Example.c glad.c maths.c 
OBJS := Example.o glad.o maths.o
exe = app 
CFLAGS = -Wno-deprecated -I./dependencies/include
LIBS += ./dependencies/library
OPENGLLIB = ./dependencies/library/libglfw.3.3.dylib 

FREETYPE_BASE = ./freetype-2.12.1/src
BASE_SOURCE := $(FREETYPE_BASE)/base/ftsystem.c \
               $(FREETYPE_BASE)/base/ftinit.c \
               $(FREETYPE_BASE)/base/ftdebug.c \
               $(FREETYPE_BASE)/base/ftbase.c \
               $(FREETYPE_BASE)/base/ftbbox.c \
               $(FREETYPE_BASE)/base/ftglyph.c 
BASE_OBJS :=$(BASE_SOURCE:.c=.o)

CFLAGS += -I./freetype-2.12.1/include \
          -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY \

app:$(OBJS) $(BASE_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPENGLLIB) -o app $(OBJS) $(BASE_OBJS) -L$(LIBS)

glad.o: glad.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c glad.c -o $@

maths.o : maths.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c maths.c -o $@

Example.o : glad.o maths.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Example.c -o $@


$(BASE_OBJS): $(BASE_SOURCE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(exe) $(BASE_OBJS)
```

Errors

```
...
uplicate symbol '_ft_alloc' in:
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftbbox.o
duplicate symbol '_FT_New_Memory' in:
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftglyph.o
duplicate symbol '_FT_Done_Memory' in:
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftglyph.o
duplicate symbol '_ft_ansi_stream_io' in:
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftglyph.o
duplicate symbol '_FT_Stream_Open' in:
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftglyph.o
duplicate symbol '_ft_ansi_stream_close' in:
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftglyph.o
duplicate symbol '_ft_free' in:
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftglyph.o
duplicate symbol '_ft_realloc' in:
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftglyph.o
duplicate symbol '_ft_alloc' in:
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o
    ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftglyph.o
ld: 40 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of questions on SO with this same problem:

```
$(BASE_OBJS): $(BASE_SOURCE)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This cannot work.  After variable expansion this rule is:

```
./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftinit.o <...> \
    : ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.c ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftinit.c <...>
```

People seem to think that make will take this rule and try to mix and match the targets and the prerequisites so that the first `.o` lines up with the first `.c`, etc. or something like that, but that's not at all what happens.  What happens is make creates one rule for each object file, where the prerequisites are all the same:

```
./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.o : ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.c ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftinit.c <...>
./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftinit.o : ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftsystem.c ./freetype-2.12.1/src/base/ftinit.c <...>
 ...
```

So every time you compile an object file you're compiling the SAME source file over and over (because the recipe compiles `$<` which is the first prerequisite).

If you look at the output that make prints out about what it's doing, you'll see this very clearly.

You don't need to even create a rule for this at all.  Make knows how to compile a source file into an object file.  Just remove the above rule altogether.  Same for your other recipes to build object files.